# Why are no changes shown in deployment

Tags: deployment, sandbox

I have deployed my first changeset (from sandbox) to my Org today, I have noticed that almost all components that have been added need to be configured again in my Org.

i.e. Tabs settings, Custom object permissions and even components listed on my customer portal.

I find it hard to believe that this is how things need to be deployed because its almost like doing the work twice, is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out where the issue lies, although all the components changes (and its dependancies were copied and deployed) the *profiles* were not, profiles which contained permissions for th new fields and custom objects.

By including these profiles in the changeset all changes now are reflected within my Org

Answer (score 1):

You moved the change set to the target org, did you find the incoming change in that org and actually deploy it? You need to take action on both ends. Also, note that in the target org you may have just validated the changes, you can do that and then choose to actually roll them out.

It definitely sounds like you've missed a step if you're having to re-create things that were added to the change set.

Comment: I have definetly validated and deployed on the target org.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the Components you need to deploy the profiles, the reason for this is in the source org for example you must have chosen which tab should be visible to which profile. So only that particular profile can view that particular tab in Source Org.
So when you deploy the components to target org it will be by default hidden to all profiles. So you need to either make change to profiles in target org or deploy the profiles to target org from source org.